# Whats the default search query(FreeText or Contains) for sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, search, keyword

I think based on the search keyword it call the query.

Contians:"sharepoint"
FreeText:"sharepoint configuration"
WildCard: "shar*"

Contains:When it will will go to contains search?

FreeText:When it will move to freetext search. How it identify to call the freetext query.

WildCard Search:how its idenfify to include the wild card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web front end uses keyword search. I would use the [SharePointSearchService](http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/) tool for information on using the webservice.